# NSubstitute - Argument matcher problem with ref / out

Tags: c#, nsubstitute

I wanna create a mock for my *MySubClass*. But, it has an argument ***ref*** in one of its methods.
The argument ***ref*** is an object of type *MyReference*. 
The problem is: I can't use the same '*reference*' **ref**  inside my class, so the conditions aren't being hitted.

```
var sub = Substitute.For<MySubClass>();
MyReference referenceForMockTest;
sub.MyMethod(Arg.Any<int>(), ref referenceForMockTest).Returns(x => { x[0] = new MyReference(); return true; });

CallerClass caller =new  CallerClass();
caller.CallMySubClass();
```

Is there any way to use argument matchers (or another way) to solve it?

I probably need something like this code:

```
var sub = Substitute.For<MySubClass>();
MyReference reference;
sub.MyMethod(Arg.Any<int>(), ref Arg.Any<MyReference>()).Returns(x => { x[0] = new MyReference(); return true; });
```

My classes are very close to this:

```
class RootClass 
{
    MySubClass subclas = new MySubClass();

    public void Process(int codeArg) 
    {
        Response response = new Response();
        response.code = 12;

        //Create MySubClass using a some creational pattern
        var MySubClass = createSubClass();

        //I wanna mock it!
        var isOk = MySubClass.MyMethod(codeArg, ref response);
        if (!isOk) 
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}

class MySubClass
{
    public bool MyMethod(int firstArg, ref Response response)
    {
        //Do something with firstArg and Response...
        //If everything is Ok, return true
        return true;
    }
}

struct Response
{
    public int code;
    public String returnedMsg;
}
```

Comment: Can you show a method you are testing?

Answer (score 1):

From [NSubstitute groups post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nsubstitute/aZVL-y1MDLw/p_Dj_bDPBQAJ):

> For the case you have shown I recommend using `.ReturnsForAnyArgs(x =>
>   ...)`.
>
> In positive news, the next release of NSubstitute is getting the
>   syntax you've shown in your second code snippet! :) (so that snippet
>   will work unchanged!) This feature is currently in the repository at
>   https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute so if you want to try a
>   local build of NSubstitute you can start using this right away.
>
> There are some more examples of working with out/ref arguments here:
>   https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/459

So in this case something like:

```
MyReference referenceForMockTest;
sub.MyMethod(0, ref referenceForMockTest)
   .ReturnsForAnyArgs(x => { x[0] = new MyReference(); return true; });
```

Also make sure that any methods you are substituting for in your classes are virtual, otherwise NSubstitute will not be able to work with them. See [Creating a substitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/) for some more information on substituting for classes.